# How do I force git to detect changed files (due to working-tree-encoding)?

Tags: git, encoding

I just found out that some files are marked as simple text when they are actually UTF16 and git doesn't like that when doing diffs.
I played around with `.gitattributes` (specifically set for those files `text working-tree-encoding=UTF-16`) then did some iconv on some files. Then I reverted all those changes (including the `.gitattributes`).
Actually did a `git reset --hard`, but some files are still messed up and git sees no differences. Also tried `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged`, but no luck.

How do I force git to actually detect the changed files?

LE: I deleted the file and restored it and it actually resolved the issue, but I don't want to do this manually (ie check all the files and delete them). Also checked the clone in another directory and the messed up file is ok.

Comment: Have you committed the changes?

Comment: Git uses its index as a cache (that's why "cache" is one of the three names for the thing called the index) to avoid touching file-system files that it doesn't have to. Certain changes to `.gitattributes` can leave these out of sync. In general, the way to clean that up, if you don't mind discarding and rebuilding the index—this can lose staged work so don't just do it without thinking!—is to remove the index entirely (`rm .git/index`), then do a mixed reset (`git reset`).

Comment: This particular cheap-and-dirty fix, of removing and rebuilding the index, may stop working at some point as Git is getting ever-fancier mechanisms to handle very large file system trees. Be aware of that and don't rely on it too much in the future either.

Comment: @SwissCodeMen Yes, but I hard reset the head back to the remote/origin so no files should be changed anymore

Comment: @torek Thanks a lot! That seems to be it. Now it shows the messed up files as modified and checking them out fixes them. You can put your comment as an answer and I will choose it.
"don't rely on it too much in the future either" hopefully I won't need to :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is (I would argue) due to a sort of a bug in Git.  Git tries, at almost all times, to keep information in its index regarding files in your working tree and how these files' content might compare to the copies that the index refers to.  That's why (and how) the index acts as a *cache*, and hence the source for the third name: Git calls its index the *staging area* as well as "the index", but in a few places, uses the term "cache".<sup>1</sup>

In any case, the `.gitattributes` file (and `.git/info/attributes`) can affect how Git does data conversions when reading from the index and writing to your working tree, or vice versa.  This means that if you *change the contents* of the `.gitattributes` file, it's possible that *some or all cached copies become invalid*.  The `git status` command and other Git commands, however, doesn't notice this.

Deleting a file from the working tree causes Git to realize that the cache information for that file is out of date.  This is, however, rather drastic.  There's another rather-drastic alternative available, which quickly invalidates Git's cache data for *all* files:

```
rm .git/index; git reset
# assumes Unix-like commands and a Unix-style shell
```

This wipes out all staged changes, but does not touch your working tree files.  **Be careful with this!  This is not an officially approved method to deal with the problem** and it may stop working in the future.

Git needs to start noticing updates to attributes files (which would help fix the problem automatically, so that you don't have to do anything yourself), and/or acquire a formal command to announce that the cache data is out of date so that you can explicitly force a refresh (`git update-index --really-refresh` is close, but doesn't actually work here).  Until then, though, if you change `.gitattributes` settings (or `core.autocrlf` settings), it's possible to force Git to rebuild the index from scratch using the remove-and-reset method here.

---

<sup>1</sup>We mostly see this now in flags: `git rm --cached`, for instance.  The *staging area* term is usually superior and `--staged` is now often an option that means exactly the same thing as `--cached`, e.g., in `git diff`.  Git isn't known for consistency, though, so `git rm` still lacks `--staged`, while `git restore` has *only* `--staged` to refer to the index copy.  Meanwhile `git apply` uses `--index` and `--cached` with different meanings and has no `--staged` option!